# Newly added drives do not appear in the raid array list (hp server and ESXi)

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid5

I recently added two physical drives into my hp server (port 2). I also add them to the raid array list, but they don't appear in it:

[image: Raid 5 : 683GB : Disk 1,2,3,4]

and:

[image: hpssacli status]

How can I add Disk 5,6 to the raid5 array list?

is everything ok??

Appreciate for any help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed after restarting the host (ESXi).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just misreading the status display in the vSphere client.

If you took the actions to add disks and expand the logical drive, then the `hpssacli` tool is your *source of truth*.

And for the vSphere client, it's reflecting the same information, but I bet the column isn't wide enough to show the additional disk numbers :)

Comment: oh, the column is wide enough, be sure! do you wanna bet ??! :D

Comment: thank you @ewwhite, please see the updated question;)